# SQL advanced where - merge two where selections in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select two different groups in my database with a single query:

Something like this:

> SELECT * FROM RECORDS
>
> WHERE DATE = 'Monday' AND plan = "Weekly"
>
> WHERE DATE = 'Wednesday' AND plan = "Daily"

Can I merge these two (or more) "wheres" in a single query? How?

I hope I was clear enough :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you after:

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM RECORDS r
WHERE (r.DATE = 'Monday' AND r.plan = "Weekly") OR 
      (r.DATE = 'Wednesday' AND r.plan = "Daily")
```

Comment: Which could be re-written like this: `... WHERE (DATE, plan) = ('Monday', "Weekly") OR (DATE, plan) = ('Wednesday', "Daily")`, and then further like this: `... WHERE (DATE, plan) IN (('Monday', "Weekly"), ('Wednesday', "Daily"))`, although I've heard MySQL is not always good at processing predicates with tuples efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use union

```
SELECT * FROM RECORDS
WHERE DATE = 'Monday' AND plan = "Weekly"
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM RECORDS
WHERE DATE = 'Wednesday' AND plan = "Daily"
```

GoodLuck!